Error calling class method pointer in C++
Given a class method pointer methodptr, if I call with a space between object pointer and method pointer dereference operator, I get the following error: expected unqualified-id before '*' token. The same error with GCC and Clang. Why?
Correct syntax:
(this ->* methodptr)();

Wrong syntax:
(this -> * methodptr)();


Because of maximal munch principle? See this answer in What is the difference between auto&& y = x and auto& &y= x in modern C++?
